# Awareness in the body : ticklish/tingling feeling

Tags: mindfulness, daily-life, satipatthana

I'm trying to anchor my awareness while sitting at the desk.

When bringing awareness to the body , I'm getting a tickling/tingling in the body .  So to make it bearable I'm trying to move attention to different body parts and it keeps following too.  So unable to hold awareness in the body for a long time.  Is there any advice/guide on this ?

Answer (score 3):

Relax your facial muscles & take an out-breath or let go of some out-breathes.

In your efforts to anchor awareness, it sounds like you are suppressing the (mental) tension stored in your physical body (which will arise into your awareness if meditating).

Balance your effort. At regular intervals, take your foot off the accelerator; ease off the throttle.

Comment: Thank you . "the (mental) tension stored in your physical body" could you please explain this bit more ?

Comment: A human being has a nervous system throughout their body, including the brain. Just the ordinary active living of life, with drives, desires, loves, pleasures, emotions, etc, results in mental tension being stored throughout the nervous system of the physical body, brain & mind. So when a person sits still in meditation & makes the mind still via observation, the still aware mind can feel the mental tension stored in the body. If the meditator remains still, the tension will start to dissolve & also be expelled by the breathing because the person is no longer created tension via 'activity'.

Comment: Thank you so much ! is there a source to get further info ?

Comment: It is a general principle. E.g., the Pali scriptures state: "Infatuated, attached, clinging to the five aggregates...craving accompanied by passion & delight...grows within him. His bodily disturbances & mental disturbances grow. His bodily torments & mental torments grow...He is sensitive both to bodily stress & mental stress (Maha-salayatanika Sutta)" and  "If a monk should wish: 'May neither my body be fatigued nor my eyes, may my mind, through lack of clinging be released from fermentations,' he should attend to this concentration through mindfulness with in-&-out breathing (Dipa Sutta).

Answer (score 3):

If you are experiencing tickling / tingling sensations ticklish feeling, then first check on the clothes you wear. Try to wear clothes loose and soft. If they restrict blood flow or put pressure on nerves, you will feel like scratching, or feeling tingling numbness. Don't wear tight pants or pants made of thick material. Take your shoes off and if your socks are thick and binding, take them off, too.

People experience all kinds of varied phenomena when trying to practice awareness / meditation. Getting itches or feeling other sensations like tingling, or feeling of lightness or a floating sensation are some of the common ones. It is because, as relaxation sets in, the nervous system begins to pass sensory signals more efficiently. They are sensory data that were kept blocked before. When the body gets relaxed or more aware, it  gives rise to these unique sensations. So try to see it as just sensation. Try not to get too excited about it. If you are practicing awareness, make it a part of the practice. Just observe as to how it come up and watch it pass away. The main thing is not to get involved. Keep your distance, and just observe.

Even if you don't feel at ease, or you can't relax, try to just observe it, without letting it rule you. Let those feelings arise and look at them mindfully. If you just sit still and observe your agitations, they will eventually pass. They come and they go. They have no real grip on you at all.

Answer (score 0):

The tingling sensation may be used to restless worry. You can just look at the sensation knowing its impermanence. More on this see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/20984/295).